# How can I append an XML document to an xml node in c# withour the root node?

Tags: c#, .net

I have tried this to get(read) the whole xml. 
here I'm able to copy the whole xml in xmlDoc, but I don't need the root node...

```
XmlNode node = ......  //node from targetxml

node.AppendChild(targetxml.ImportNode(xmlDoc.DocumentElement));
```

I have also tried this, but not working properly not giving me all the elements in the root node

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
{
    node.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(readxml.DocumentElement.FirstChild, true));
    readxml.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(readxml.DocumentElement.FirstChild);                  
}
```

How can I trim the root node???

it some what like this

//before appending

```
<tests program="XXX">//root node
```

//some data

```
</tests>
```

//after appending

```
<tests program="XXX">//root node
```

//some data

```
  <tests program="XXX">//don't need this(tests) node but require all the child node
```

//other data (all this data is required)

```
 </tests>

</tests>
```

how can i remove the inner test node

Comment: Do you have to use the "old" API? LINQ to XML usually makes all this sort of thing simpler.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What will become the root node?  Can you show a "before and after" of the XML?

Answer (score 0):

right now i m doing like this

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = readxml.SelectNodes("/tests/*");
           for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
           {
               node.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(readxml.DocumentElement.FirstChild, true));
               readxml.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(readxml.DocumentElement.FirstChild);
           }
```

but any alternate way???